# Error with PFObject does not have a member named 'Contains' (SWIFT Xcode Parse)

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfobject

So I'm trying to create a registration page with availability by Zip Code. For instance, a user can only register if the service is available in their area (zip code).

This is my current code, it checks what the user typed in the TextField and compared is to a string in my Parse database, if it matches; they can sign up and a new viewController will open up.

Except I have 1 error only.

```
class checkAvailability: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var zipCode: UITextField!
@IBAction func checkAvailBtn(sender: AnyObject) {
    checkZip()
}

func checkZip() {
    let usersZipCode = zipCode.text
    let query = PFQuery(className:"zipCodes")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            // The find succeeded.
            print("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) zip codes.")
            // Do something with the found objects
            if let zipCodes = objects as? [PFObject] {
                if zipCodes.contains({ $0["zipCodes"] as! String == usersZipCode }) { **THIS IS THE LINE WITH THE ERROR**
                    println()("your in!") // transition to the new screen
                    performSegueWithIdentifier("beginSignUp", sender: self)
                }
                else {
                    println("your out.") // do whatever
                }
            }
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            print("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

The error is:

> [PFObject] does not have a member named 'contains'.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: why do you even need contains? just write normal if ( if zipCodes["zipCodes"] as! String == usersZipCode ..)

Comment: This won't work because I'll get an error stating "Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `contains` method is only available in Swift 2 within the Xcode 7 environment. You're using Swift 1.2, and there's no `contains` there.

Solution: Compile your code in Xcode 7 beta